# Run __init__ only in base class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'd like to have an `__init__()` method that runs only in the base class, but does not run in the child classes.

Given the code here:

```
class base:

    def __init__(self):
        print('Only print this if I am base')

class ext(base):
    ...

foo = ext()
```

I get the following result:

```
Only print this if I am base
```

Which I am not, so that's not what I want.

The solution may simply be a better architecture.  Clearly `ext` is not *really* an extension of `base` since `base` does things that `ext` does not do.

Perhaps double inheritance is the solution.  Have base inherit from `i_print_an_init_message` class and put the `__init__()` in there. Though that seems overkill.

Also checking the name of the class to see if the name is `base` seems kludgy.

Or, maybe I just have an argument in the init that defaults to `False`.

Is there any particularly pythonic way of doing this?

(Please assume I've answered all the "Why are you doing this?" comments. Thanks!)

Comment: why not defining an `__init__` method in `ext` which _does not_ call the base class init?

Comment: If you want `ext.__init__` to behave differently from `base.__init__`, then you need to override it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre definitely a possibility, but what if the user forgets?

Comment: then raise an exception at the end of the base init, that you'll catch when you instanciate the base class.

Comment: I think I'm talking myself into the argument solution.

Comment: In general, a subclass can add or change functionality, but cannot *remove* it. It sounds like `ext` and `base` should both extend a 3rd common parent.

Comment: looks like an anti-pattern...

Answer (score 2):

There should probably be a third class that acts as the parent for both `base` and `ext`.

```
class RealBase:
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class Base(RealBase):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Only print this if I am base')


class Ext(RealBase):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

`Ext` should not extend `Base` if its instances aren't really instances of `Base`. You should be able to use an instance of a child class anywhere you could use an instance of its parent.

Comment: that looks way cleaner than my hack.

Answer (score 1):

you can either override `__init__` or hack your way around it with something like

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__ == base:
            print('Only print this if I am base')
```

if you want `base.__init__` to do stuff `ext.__init__` should not do. but that might be a sign that you should change your design... (e.g. something like what [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561164/4954037) suggests).

Comment: Ha!  Cool SNOWCRASH reference!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the argument solution is the best one. Only a person using the base would know to pass the 'top' argument, otherwise we get the required behavior.

```
class base:

    def __init__(self, top=False):
        if top:
            print('Only print this if I am base')

class ext(base):
...

foo = ext()
```

Comment: This is similar to "security by obscurity". It might not be *obvious* that you can write `ext(True)`, but you certainly *can*.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you need only define a constructor in the derived class that overloads the constructor of the base class:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        print ('base')


class ext(base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('ext')


foo = ext()
```

Which produces output:

```
ext
```

as opposed to a constructor that does:

```
class base:
    def __init__(self):
        print ('base')


class ext(base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('ext')


foo = ext()
```

which produces output:

```
base
ext
```